# Ada - How to control decimal places when printing Duration data type?

Tags: ada

This is my print statement:

```
 timeInMili: duration;

 timeInMili := (finish - start)*1000;

 Put_Line(duration'image(timeInMili));
```

(multiplying by 1000 to change in to milliseconds from seconds)

The above produces alot of decimal places. Can someone please show me an example of how to print with a set number of decimal places.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ada.Text_IO.Fixed_IO is a generic package for fix-point types that provides better control over the output format than the `'Image` attribute.

An example:

```
with Ada.Text_IO; use Ada.Text_IO;
procedure Foo is
    package Duration_IO is new Fixed_IO(Duration);
    timeInMili: Duration := 1.0 / 3.0;
begin
    Duration_IO.Put(timeInMili, Fore => 0, Aft => 2);
    New_Line;
end Foo;
```

Output:

```
0.33
```

Comment: When i try to add the Ada.Duration_Io library, it says it not a predefined library.

Comment: @Nwqp There's no `Ada.Duration_IO`, and I don't see `Ada.Duration_IO` in Keith's answer.  His code defines a new `Duration_IO` package by instantiating `Ada.Text_IO.Fixed_IO`.

Comment: I love the nautical feel of the optional `Fore` and `Aft` parameters. Intuitive, brief, and keeps the code shipshape and in Bristol fashion....